# Google oAuth2 flow - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, torii

I have an SPA hosted at http://localhost:4200
I also have an API hosted at http://localhost:1337

My SPA is using Torii to handle the flow and I get back the authorizationCode which I then try to send to my server for processing.

Here is my configuration over at google:

[image: Google oAuth config]

As you can see I've included all of the possible URLs just in case!

Now, when I pass that authorizationCode to my server to validate and then provide the client with a session I always get back `redirect_uri_mismatch` - even though I can see in the request to google the redirectUrl is exactly what is listed in the oAuth config page:

> http://localhost:1337/api/v1/auths/google_oauth2

Am I doing this wrong? Should I be able to kick off the process from the browser then validate the authorizationCode from the server?

I can confirm that the api key and client id and secret are all correct.

[UPDATE]

Here is the repo: https://github.com/wayne-o/ember-waterlock-example

Comment: Easy answer for testing on localhost:  Create a native client not a web browser one.  (type other)   if you want to actually get it to work try removing the port in Google developer console http://localhost/authorize/ works sometimes  basically what ever port the redirect_uri_missmatch says you are calling from put that in minus the port  http://localhost/api/v1/auths/google_oauth2

Comment: Hey, if i try it with client "other" I just get unauthorized_client - this is such a nause! it was working earlier until I tried to "clean up" now everything is as it was and nothing works...

Comment: I also tried removing ports which didn't work :/

Comment: I've tried creating a whole new web app config on google and re-tested and I get the same error. I wonder if I need to start killing goats or something?

Comment: that will teach you to "clean up".   Rule nr 1. if it works don't mess with it.

Comment: How about using `http://127.0.0.1:1337` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: still getting redirect_uri_mismatch - should I be able to validate the authorizationCode from my server when the SPA requested it originally form a different URL?

Comment: @iwayneo so your web browser actually says `localhost:4200`? Then in that case, you definitely should return back to `http://localhost:4200/api/v1/auths/google_oauth2` as well.

Comment: I am returning back to that and I am getting an auth code. what I want is for the API to also validate that code so that the API knows who it is talking to

Comment: I can commit the code later - this is for a demo I'm doing in node / ember so you can have a ganders if you're familiar with the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this the source and redirect url needs to be the same. This is a pain as i've read in the google docs that you can share auth codes across various application "packages" which might be hosted in different places.

Anyway - to make this work you can proxy the API through ember using the following command:

```
ember server --proxy http://localhost:1337
```

Then configure everything to run through http://localhost:4200 - including all of the URLs you might have over at google oauth console.

From there on in all of your wildest dreams come true.

It's lame as AFAICS this should work without the need for all this.